# laravel run command / cron every 7 seconds on sunday

Tags: php, laravel, cron, command

So i would like to accomplish the a command which runs every sunday but also every 7 seconds on that sunday.

The following is from the docs but I don't have an idea on how to achieve this. Anyone able to direct me in the right direction?

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('test:cron')
             ->everyMinute();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will run the command sunday every minute:

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('test:cron')->cron('* * * * SUN');
}
```

Check it [here](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_SUN)

PS: I don't think you can use cron to go lower than "every minute".

Comment: This worked like a charm, tested on today's note, I didn't think this would suffice my needs but it does exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you cannot achieve this via the scheduler API.
However, you could run a custom command/job on sundays every minutes like this :

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new Job)
             ->sundays()
             ->everyMinutes();
}
```

Then in your job, call the CLI command you need to run, sleep for seven seconds and repeat this process for 1 minutes.
Finally, make sure to take a look at the Laravel documentation about Jobs : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues
For instance, using symfony/process :

```php
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class RunCommand implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $process = new Process(['ls', '-lsa']);


        for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) {
            // Run the command
            $process->run();

            // Pause the execution during 7 seconds
            sleep(7);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach aswell, it's a small task so I chose the above answer but this is definitely one to look out for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In `app/Console/Kernel.php`

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('test:cron')->cron('*/7 * * * 7')->runInBackground();
}
```

> => `*/7` => every 7 Seconds
>
> => `*` => every Hour
>
> => `*` => every day in the month
>
> => `*` => every month
>
> => `7` => day in week `*` every day `0-6` Sunday to Saturday `7` mean `Sunday`

**Enable crontab in `linux`**

```
crontab -e
```

*will open file text to add this*

```
* * * * * php /var/www/path of project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```